# Specifying which data to display based on ID using Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a web application that contains a link towards the "album" section of my application. My problem right now is that it's showing the albums created for ALL users (and this goes the same for all members within the application). I want that whenever a user who is logged in selects the "phots" link, he/she is directed into the album page where they can only see the pictures that THEY uploaded.

To begin, this is the schema wherein the photos are being uploaded into.:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `content` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`node_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`party_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`category` text,
`title` text,
`content` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`content_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`country` text NOT NULL,
`view_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
`attribute1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`attribute2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`liked` text,
`approved` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

Then this is where the album is being viewed:

```
    <div class="photodiv">
<?php

    foreach ($albumArr as $album)
    {
    Yii::app()->user->id;
        $image = Image::model()->findByAttributes(array('content_id'=>$album->id, 'attribute1'=>'1'));
        $photos =   Image::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('content_id'=>$album->id));

        echo '<div class="albumdiv">';
        echo '<div class="picdiv">';
        if (!empty($image))
        {
            echo '<a href="'.Yii::app()->createUrl('image/index',array('album'=>$album->content)).'"><img src="'.Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/albums/'.$album->content.'/'.$image->id.$image->content.'" height="100px" width="100px" /></a>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<center><a href="'.Yii::app()->createUrl('image/index',array('album'=>$album->content)).'"><h4>'.$album->content.'</h4></a></center>';
        echo count($photos) == 1 ? '<center><h5>'.count($photos).' photo</h5></center>' : '<center><h5>'.count($photos).' photos</h5></center>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
</div>
```

If you are wondering how this was generated, the controller contained the following:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
        $usertag = isset($_GET['usertag']) ? addslashes($_GET['usertag']) : FALSE;
        $users = new CActiveDataProvider('SystemUser', array(
            'id' => '',
            'criteria' => array(
                    'alias'=>'u',
                    'join'=>'JOIN persons p ON u.party_id = p.party_id JOIN lookup_codes lc ON p.country = lc.id',
                    'condition' => $usertag ? 'status != "Approved" AND company_name LIKE "%'.$usertag.'%" OR status = "'.$usertag.'"' : 'status != "Approved"',
                    //'order'=> 'date_created DESC'
                    'order'=> 'status'
                ),
            'pagination' => array(
                'pageSize' => 100
            )
        ));

        $data = array(
            'dataProvider' => $users
            );

        $this->render('index', $data);
}
```

And index rendered the _view which I showed 2 scripts ago.

My problem is I'm not quite sure how to display only the specific creator of the album. In this case, 'party_id' is the ID that identifies who the creator is.

Comment: which table in your database contains party_id as primary key? I mean party_id is foreign key here so it must be a primary key in some table so please specify that table.

Comment: party_id is from the persons table. I didn't think it was relevant to put it since I could just call the party_id from this table aka 'content'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok If i understood you correctly then I am making some assumptions prior to answer your question. 
1. Normally user table is used to login a user and store credentials like username,password, rememberme, and other attributes, but in your case i assume you are using person table for logging in a user.
2. In userIdentity.php you are using person model for verification purpose. 

Then you need to do like this.
First create a function in your UserIdentity.php file

```
public function getId()
{
    return $this->_id;
}
```

it will return the id of the person. 
Now in your view file you can use this code to get id of logged in user

```
$id=Yii::app()->user->getId()
```

Now you can use it in your criteria like

```
 $image = Image::model()->findByAttributes(array('content_id'=>$album->id,'party_id'=>$id, 'attribute1'=>'1'));
 $photos =   Image::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('content_id'=>$album->id,'party_id'=>$id,));
```

This will give you the results on for the logged in user.
**Edit:**
*For your next question*
If you are able to display a link and pass some user id in that link then you can do like this. 
1. Where you are showing the link for a user pass this link id of that user like

```
CHtml::link('ViewAlbum',array('controller/userAlbum',array('id'=>userId)))
```

2. Create action for specific user

```
public function actionUserAlbum($id)
    {
        album=Album::model()->findAllByAttributes(array(
    'id_of_creator_of_album'=>$id;
    ));
    $this->render('someView',array('id'=>$id))

    }
```

then use us this id in your view to get photos related to that album

Comment: This is actually part of the answer I was looking for. So far, I'm getting only the results for the given user (which is correct) but I'm also trying to create a link that passes different ID's so that any user can view the album of a given user. I have a page that lists all current users and I was able to get the ID , but I do not know how to pass that onto a link.

Comment: I was able to create a link and pass the ID variable for the specific user, but I do not know how to retrieve it and use it inside the album.

Comment: hmm, added code, please see if it helps and let me know if some complication

Comment: I asked a new question as I feel it would be more appropriate that way. You can find it here:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978092/trying-to-pass-a-variable-into-a-link-and-using-it-in-a-view-in-yii

Comment: i think the question is removed

Comment: Yeah. I was able to figure it out!